# Return dictionary instead of list of dictionaries

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a model which contain two fields. One field I want to be the key and second the content

I want my Modelserializer to return a dictionary that contain column1 value as a key and column2 value like value:

```
{
  "column1Value": "column2Value",
  "column2Value": "column2Value",
  "column3Value": "column3Value"
}
```

right now my serializer is returning something like this

```
[
  {
    "columnField1Name": "field1",
    "columnField2Name": "field2",
  }
     ....
]
```

Thanks!

model.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
  code = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
  content = models.TextField()
```

serializers.py

```
class TestSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Test
      fields = ['code', 'content']
```

Comment: Please show the serializer and your models

Comment: i added the serializer and the model. There are very simple

Comment: Do you want to fetch all the objects from the model or just one?

Comment: I want from list of dictionaries (this is what return the modelSerializer by default) to return a dictionary (only one) where the key of dictonary is the model field1 and the value is the field2 of the model.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it not sure if it is best suited for your use case.

Add a `SerializerMethodField()` in your serializer class and in the method definition create a dictionary for each model instance.

```
class TestSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    
    field_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   
   class Meta:
      model = Test
      fields = ['field_name']
    
    def get_field_name(self, obj):

        column1value = obj.column1
        column2value = obj.column2

        return {
            str(column1value) : str(column2value)
        }
```

However, `field_name` from serialized data will be a dictionary. To turn it into your expected formate you can merge each dictionary of list into an empty dictionary.

```
some_dict = {}

for dicti in field_name:
    some_dict.update(dicti)
```

You can do this in your **views.py**.